# How to store html files on an XAMPP test server?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to test out some basic AJAX programs but I can't figure out where to put them or how to set up a file directory to run them on XAMPP (MAC). Could anyone provide some clarity on this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

open your XAMPP folder[if you search it on your mac you ll find it = /Applications/XAMPP] then put all html files in htdocs folder. they will available through `http://localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Go to installation directory and put them in `htdocs` folder. You can then access these files in the address bar using: `http://localhost/YOUR-PATH-IN-HTDOCS-FOLDER`

Answer (score 0):

The `htdocs` folder of XAMPP is the public directory by default. If you're using Windows look in the `C:\xampp\htdocs` path.

Comment: OP asks about MAC in question

Comment: Still since I don't know about Mac I'm answering for Windows for anyone coming to this question for help who does have Windows.